# Exporting to excel from Delphi without having excel

Tags: delphi, excel, export-to-excel

I'm looking to export data to excel from Delphi without having to own a copy of excel, is this possible?

N.B. CSV will not do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FlexCel, earlier an Opensource now managed by TMS (http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcel.asp) works great.

You can also check TmxNativeExcel at http://www.torry.net. Comes free and is uses native Biff format. I've not tried this though.

Answer (score 12):

Try [zexmlss](http://avemey.com/zexmlss/index.php?lang=en). This library can create and load excel 2003 XML format files. Support merged cells, borders, vertical and horizontal alignment and other. Zlib license. Work with delphi 6, 7, 9-14 and lazarus.

Comment: For the record: lib moved to GitHub and has one fork ATM. Neither me no Avemey have time now to converge the changes. He mostly focused on FPC and ODS format while i had to work on XE2 and XLSX. And obiously we have different tastes about coding style :-)

Comment: I can recommend [zexmlss](http://avemey.com/zexmlss/index.php?lang=en) - seems to work well for XLSX and ODT, does formatting, formulas, and it's free. I had to make a _small_ change to the code to get it to compile in Delphi 10 Seattle, but it's rocking

Comment: I have tried but failed - there is problem with zip facilities, can not be added.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's possible to create MS Office documents as HTML. You don't need to open them in a web browser then or anything, the file can still have the extension .xls and open in Excel like normal.

I just created a new spreadsheet and stuck the numbers 1-3 in the first three cells of column A, and saved it as HTML. There was a bunch of extra mess that probably isn't all necessary. I stripped out as much as I could, here's what looks to be the bare minimum to produce a working spreadsheet.

Try creating a new text file with this as its contents, and save it with a .xls extension.

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetOptions>
     <x:Selected/>
     <x:Panes>
      <x:Pane>
       <x:Number>3</x:Number>
       <x:ActiveRow>3</x:ActiveRow>
      </x:Pane>
     </x:Panes>
     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
    </x:WorksheetOptions>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<table x:str>
    <tr>
        <td x:num width=64>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td x:num>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td x:num>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems a great solution, thanks Matt. Works in Excel 2003 but I'm not sure if users will have to install the compatibility download for Office 2010, for the HTML format you propose to be usable.  Have anyone tried this with other Office versions?

Comment: Cool u saved me hours of searching a library

Answer (score 6):

oExport - XLSX/ODS native Delphi import/export library

- no external dll libraries are required
- no dependency on Excel or Calc installation (no OLE)
- full unicode support even for D7, D2007
- supported cell types: string, number, percent, formula, time, date, datetime
- cell formatting: cell width+height, horizontal+vertical alignment, wrap text, font, background color, borders
- col/row span
- tested and working under Delphi 2007 and XE2 32bit+64bit: should be compatible with all D7 to XE2
- NEW OFiller: fill DOCX (Word 2007), ODT (OpenOffice Writer), XLSX (Excel 2007), ODS (OpenOffice Calc) templates

http://www.kluug.at/xlsx-ods-delphi.php

licensed under a MPL/GPL/LGPL tri-license
Version: MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0/LGPL 2.1

Comment: Please don't add this to lots of questions.

Comment: Not (or no longer) open-source though

Comment: OExport does not compile - OWideSupport unit not found!

Answer (score 2):

SMExport from Scalabium ([scalabium.com](http://scalabium.com/)) includes lots of formats, including Excel format with or without having Excel installed.

Answer (score 0):

NativeExcel mentioned earlier is from Nika-Soft. Not free, but it works fine. I am using it now for over one year without problems. http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcel2/

Answer (score 0):

## TXLSFile library v.4.0. and XLSExport components

We've used successfully with D2007, D2009 & D2010

### What is TXLSFile

```
  TXLSFile is a Delphi library for reading and writing MS Excel 
  XLS files. It is based on direct reading and writing of files, 
  and works without OLE Automation with Microsoft Excel. 

  TXLSFile is  distributed  with  XLSExport  components  package. 
  XLSExport is a Delphi components package  for quick data 
  export  into  MS Excel file with  one line  of code.
```

http://sm-software.com

Answer (score -1):

theree is a very simple way to achive this and is by use of a text file. Simply output the data, each field followed by a comma, followed by a carriage return. Save this file with a .CSV extension. This should still work on Excel; I use Open Officw these days

Comment: The OP said: "N.B. CSV will not do."