# Open source component or unit for exporting Delphi TDataSet to native XLS without Excel installed

Tags: delphi, excel, export, components, export-to-excel

Do you possibly know about the existence of a free and open sourced Delphi code to export TDataSet to native XLS format? The question was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493071/exporting-to-excel-from-delphi-without-having-excel), yet I am looking for a free solution.

As observed in for example TeeChart.TeeStore.TSeriesDataXLS.SaveToStream writing a native XLS export function is not a rocket science, yet I struggle to find an existing solution, which would definitely save some time and money (for commercial component which would be used in 10-20%).

It would be beneficial if such export code would allow color and text style changes, but for me personally it is not crucial.

Comment: +1. What's *"not constructive"* about this question?

Comment: Indeed. 1k views, (almost) all responses on topic. SO becomes something different nowadays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used the components **mxExport** from Max. It's free and with source code avaible.   The page it's now offline (http://www.maxcomponents.net/) but you can find the components in other places:

- [Torry](http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=mxexport&Title=Yes)
- [FTP ClubDelphi](http://www.terawiki.com/clubdelphi/Delphi/Componentes-Funciones/__MaxComponents__/) (all components libraries of Max)
- ...

Check components: mxExports and mxNativeExcel.

Regards.

Comment: mxNativeExcel doesn't support TDataSet as input though it's easy to use, +1
accepted for mxExport - this one saves TDataSet, thx.

Comment: Tried this not long ago, and Excel 2013 choke on a file produced with it...

Answer (score 5):

oExport - XLSX/ODS native Delphi import/export library

- no external dll libraries are required
- no dependency on Excel or Calc installation (no OLE)
- full unicode support even for D7, D2007
- supported cell types: string, number, percent, formula, time, date, datetime
- cell formatting: cell width+height, horizontal+vertical alignment, wrap text, font, background color, borders
- col/row span
- tested and working under Delphi 2007 and XE2 32bit+64bit: should be compatible with all D7 to XE2
- NEW OFiller: fill DOCX (Word 2007), ODT (OpenOffice Writer), XLSX (Excel 2007), ODS (OpenOffice Calc) templates

http://www.kluug.at/xlsx-ods-delphi.php

licensed under a MPL/GPL/LGPL tri-license
Version: MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0/LGPL 2.1

----update
i think it's commercial now :(

Answer (score 3):

give [smExport](http://www.scalabium.com/sme/) a try. Not free, but reasonably priced with 35€ / 50 € (without/ with source). They also have a trial version (limited by the number of rows you can export).
In addition it supports exports into lots of other formats.