# How would you display a DBGrid's contents in a table within a Word or RTF document?

Tags: delphi, reporting, rtf

I'm using Rave to generate reports, but it's poor at generating Word docs. My reporting needs are simple; the only thing I can't do easily within code is make a table. I'd love suggestions about how to display a [DB]Grid's contents (or underlying ClientDataSet records) within a bordered table, in Word or RTF compatible format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the same component that I have recomended [here (mxExports from max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457472/open-source-component-or-unit-for-exporting-delphi-tdataset-to-native-xls-without).

**mxExport** can export a TDataset, TStringGrid and TDBGrid to differents file formats, including RTF and MS Word.

See the component and test the demos. It can be usefull for you. It's free and source included.  ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias para la respuesta! ... Do you know whether I could use this component to insert the exported grid within a file? In other words, create a file with text, then the table, and then more text?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use Office Automation. At the risk of blowing my own trumpet, I have blogged on this subject several times -
http://nbnewman.blogspot.com/search/label/office%20automation. It's no problem to add text to a Word file, then add a table and then add more text.

Comment: @AlC; 
"I could use this component to insert the exported grid within a file?"
The component exports the data into a file. ¿I don't understand this cuestion?

Comment: No'am -- thank you; I'll take a look at your blog. ... Netfali -- I think what I was talking about would be like adding the data into the middle of a file. Try to imagine a file with text (not from mxExports), then a grid (from mxExports), then some more text (not from mxExports). It sounds like mxExports does not do that directly, but I will take a look at it and explore. Thank you again for responding.

Comment: Hello AIC.
OK, now i have understand what you need. ;-)
Maybe you can complete the task with automation, as said No'am.
You can also try to modify/review the source code and modify it.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you have to make a template .doc file, in which you are going to create keywords that are going to be replaced... Here you are one example code...

```
<br> 
var
 FileName: OleVariant;
<br> Doc : _Document;
 <br>SearchText, ReplaceText, Wrap, All: OleVariant;
<br>
<br> begin
  <br>WordApplication1.Connect;
  <br>WordApplication1.visible:= True;

 <br> FileName:=GetCurrentDir+'\Documents\In_orders.doc';
  <br>WordApplication1.Documents.Open(FileName,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam);
  <br>Doc := WordApplication1.ActiveDocument;
  <br>WordDocument1.ConnectTo(Doc);
<br>  WordApplication1.Disconnect;

  <br>SearchText := 'order_nomer';
   <br>ReplaceText := dbgrid1. < some property.. >;
    <br>Wrap := wdFindContinue;
   <br>All := wdReplaceAll;
  <br>WordDocument1.Content.Find.Execute(SearchText, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, Wrap, EmptyParam, ReplaceText, EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam);
<br>
 <br>WordApplication1.Disconnect;
 <br>end;
```